# Функция для вывода значений, по цепочке ключей многомерного массива

Tags: php, массивы

Хочу немного упростить функцию для вывода значений из многомерного массива. Допустим есть некий массив

```
$arr['val1']['val2']['val3'] = 100;
```

нужная функция

```
function array_output($arr)
{
  ....
}
```

результат ее работы

```
echo array_output(['val1']['val2']['val3']); // 100
```

в общем нужна функция которая по элементу массива, выдает его значение.

Comment: Я не очень понимаю, то есть вам нужно чтобы вы вводили в функцию нужные ключи а функция возвращала то что лежит по этим ключам?

Comment: да именно это и нужно, это конечно можно вывести просто указав ключи в переменной, но хотелось создать для этого функцию.

Comment: Так а в чем проблема сразу писать так? `echo $are['key']['keyLala']`?

Comment: Евгений Иванов, на данный момент у меня есть функция, которая отдает мне многомерный массив и когда мне нужно вывести значения, я создаю переменную и присваиваю ей значение этой функции. И уже потом вывожу так как вы указали. Но хотелось бы убрать присваивание и сразу передавать значение цепочки ключей той функции, а она мне отдавала не весь массив, а лишь значение ключей.

Comment: @Денис так а как вы собираетесь передавать `['val1']['val2']['val3']` если это не валидная строка.

Comment: @Manitikyl в том то и дело, я пока не придумал как эту функцию реализовать, поэтому и создал тут свой вопрос, это вообще возможно или нет?

Comment: Зависит от того что вы хотите `array_output(['val1']['val2']['val3']);` - это невозможно. `array_output('val1,val2,val3');` - это возможно.

Comment: @Manitikyl а по вашему примеру, по подробнее, можно увидеть реализацию?

Answer (score 1):

Не понятно только как должен передаваться `$arr` для этой функции;

```
$arr['val1']['val2']['val3'] = 100;

function array_output($vals)
{
  global $arr;

  $vals = explode(',', $vals);
  $return = $arr;
  foreach ($vals as $value) {
    $return = $return[$value];
  }

  return $return;
}

var_dump(array_output('val1,val2,val3'));
```

Comment: а если допустим заключить эту цепочку в массив и тогда передавать как массив данных, тогда ведь получится отправлять такие данные, но тогда как по  такому массиву искать его совпадение в исходном массиве и вывести его значение?

Comment: @Денис покажите именно что вы хотите передавать и как. Прям `array_output(....)`

Comment: если вот так передавать array_output([['val1']['val2']['val3']]); или это тоже невалидно и лучше оставить данную затею вообще)) Я думал есть простое решение, такие сложные функции усложнят все, и выйдет неоправданное усложнения класса.

Comment: @Денис `array_output([['val1']['val2']['val3']]);` - тоже невалидно. лучше оставить идею.

Comment: сделал по другому, оказывается такая запись работает не только с переменными, но и с функциями, поэтому можно было записать вот так и это работало $this->connection()['message']['reply_to_message']

Comment: @Денис ага, только почему-то таких подробностей про `$this->connection()` мы не увидели в вопросе. Если хотите получать правильные ответы, задавайте правильные вопросы.